# Best hot liquor pumps

Tags: pump

My surflow Brewbuddy pump has had a good long life and is ready for its replacement.

What hot liquor pumps are recommended?
features required:

- adjustable flow rate
- handles boiling liquids
- easy to clean
- needs little to no priming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agree on the March pump.  The 809 HS is a great pump.  It is easy to build an intake and output for it to help control the flow speed.  You should also add an air bleed valve to the output side so that you can help gravity by letting the air out of your output line.

Here's a link to a photo of [my pump with plumbing](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/XS_hlLTpiC0l0bPVJ6EBZJvcTMYk_HE9gFb_wNKjZbg?feat=directlink).

The input should be on the bottom so that gravity will pull the liquid into the pump body as best as possible.    You can see in the picture the bleed valve off to the side on the output (top).  To use it, just open the input valve all the way, open the valve on your source, and then open the bleed part way.  When you get a little bit of liquid out of the bleed, shut the bleed, switch the pump on, and slowly open the output valve.

The nice thing about this pump is that you can leave it running all day with no liquid in it and it will not burn up.  It is just a simple magnetic impeller.  It is all boil safe and is food grade plastic.  The wet end can be rotated 90 degrees so you can orient the input and output threads any way you want (but you want it with the input on the bottom).  The dry end (motor housing) should be protected.  It is not water proof.  But a simple piece of flashing will protect it from normal splashing.  I've seen people build the pump into a tupperware container with the valves sticking through the walls of the container.  That works well too.  I also suggest a nice heavy base to mount it to.  I used a cross of 4x4.  Finally, buy a GFCI outlet adapter.  Protect yourself.  It also acts as an on/off switch (reset/test).

To clean it, I just run my sanitizing fluid through it for a minute or so.  After that, I just hang it on a hook on the ceiling with the wet end down and valves open.  That way it will drain.  (I store it in my garage and I don't want water in it to freeze and bust it).

A setup like this is well worth the money and time.

Comment: looks like MoreBeer moving to the March H315HF from the 805 HS http://morebeer.com/view_product/11622/103556/March_High_Temperature_Brewing_Pump_-_High_Flow

Answer (score 2):

I use a March 809 HS and I love it.  You install a ball valve on the out put to control flow rate.  While it's not self priming, it requires very little height differential to get it primed.

Comment: I had a bit of a problem with the surflow using a ball value to adjust flow as it starting causing aeration (small leak I think).  Does the March do well at lower flow rates (like w RIMS liquor return)?

Comment: Yeah, my 809 seems to work really well at low flow rates.  I have to have the valve almost completely closed to prevent cavitation when I pump boiling wort through it and it works fine.